# Erdas LPS : how to rename points_ID values?

Tags: editing, erdas-imagine, photogrammetry, imagine-photogrammetry

I'm working with ERDAS LPS 2014, i would like edit the name given for my GCPs and TPs (add the following suffix : "_w").

I tried to do that using the "formula" menu... in vain. I did not find a function able to do this task.

Thus, I tried to export my column "point_id" into a text format. I succeed to importing and i succeed in editing my useful field with Excel. But, however, I do not manage to reimport my new edited text file into ERDAS LPS.

Could you throw light for me and tell me how to rename values for the points_id with erdas LPS?